# Symfony Acl: How i can add custom mask (MaskBuilder)?

Tags: symfony, acl

I want to add `print` or `something` to mask builder. How i can?
From official cookbook (http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/acl.html#cumulative-permissions) i don't see how to add special masks.

**Example:**

```
$builder = new MaskBuilder();
$builder
    ->add('view')
    ->add('edit')
    ->add('delete')
    ->add('undelete')
;
$mask = $builder->get(); // int(29)
```

**From my question i want to:**

```
$builder = new MaskBuilder();
$builder
    ->add('view')
    ->add('print')
    ->add('or-something-i-want')
;
$mask = $builder->get();
```

Comment: I don't uderstand actually what are you want to do. Can you edit your question and add more details?

Comment: @freetrace i have edit my question to explain what i want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You need to create your own MAskBuilder that extend from default

```
namespace Acm\DefaultBundle\Permission;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder as BaseMaskBuilder;


class MaskBuilder extends BaseMaskBuilder {

  const MASK_PRINT = 256; // 1 << 8
  const CODE_PRINT = 'A';   }
```

2-  You need to replace the PermissionMap

```
namespace Acm\DefaultBundle\Permission;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\BasicPermissionMap;  
use Acm\DefaultBundle \Permission\MaskBuilder;

class PermissionMap extends BasicPermissionMap {


const PERMISSION_PRINT    = 'PRINT';
const PERMISSION_VIEW        = 'VIEW';
const PERMISSION_EDIT        = 'EDIT';
const PERMISSION_CREATE      = 'CREATE';
const PERMISSION_DELETE      = 'DELETE';
const PERMISSION_UNDELETE    = 'UNDELETE';
const PERMISSION_OPERATOR    = 'OPERATOR';
const PERMISSION_MASTER      = 'MASTER';
const PERMISSION_OWNER       = 'OWNER';

private $map = array(
    self::PERMISSION_VIEW => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_VIEW,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),
    self::PERMISSION_PRINT => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_PRINT,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,),

    self::PERMISSION_EDIT => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_CREATE => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_CREATE,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_DELETE => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_DELETE,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_UNDELETE => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_UNDELETE,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_OPERATOR => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_MASTER => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_OWNER => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),
);

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getMasks($permission, $object)
{
    if (!isset($this->map[$permission])) {
        return null;
    }

    return $this->map[$permission];
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function contains($permission)
{
    return isset($this->map[$permission]);
}
```

}

3- Add this to your config.yml to replace the default PermissionsMap

```
parameters:
   security.acl.permission.map.class: Pitchbull\CalendarBundle\Permission\Permission\PermissionMap
```

4- You now can check by is is granted by PRINT

```
     $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');

     // check for apply access
     if false === $securityContext->isGranted('PRINT', $service)) {

        //your access is denied
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to extend `MaskBuilder` and override the constants:

```
namespace Your\AclBundle\Permission;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder;

class YourMaskBuilder extends MaskBuilder
{
    const MASK_VIEW = 1; // 1 << 0
    const MASK_PRINT = 2; // 1 << 1
    const MASK_WHATYOUWANT = 4; // 1 << 2
    // ...

    const CODE_VIEW = 'V';
    const CODE_PRINT = 'P';
    const CODE_WHATYOUWANT = 'W';
    // ...
}
```

And use:

```
$builder = new YourMaskBuilder();
$builder
    ->add('view')
    ->add('print')
    ->add('whatyouwant')
;
$mask = $builder->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

just in addition to @Duvan s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23961720/1468708)
In the current symfony version you'll have to override the map like this:

```
namespace Acm\DefaultBundle\Permission;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\BasicPermissionMap;  
use Acm\DefaultBundle \Permission\MaskBuilder;

class PermissionMap extends BasicPermissionMap {

const PERMISSION_PRINT       = 'PRINT';
const PERMISSION_VIEW        = 'VIEW';
const PERMISSION_EDIT        = 'EDIT';
const PERMISSION_CREATE      = 'CREATE';
const PERMISSION_DELETE      = 'DELETE';
const PERMISSION_UNDELETE    = 'UNDELETE';
const PERMISSION_OPERATOR    = 'OPERATOR';
const PERMISSION_MASTER      = 'MASTER';
const PERMISSION_OWNER       = 'OWNER';

protected $map

public function __construct(){

    $this->map = array(
    self::PERMISSION_VIEW => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_VIEW,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),
    self::PERMISSION_PRINT => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_PRINT,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,),

    self::PERMISSION_EDIT => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_CREATE => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_CREATE,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_DELETE => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_DELETE,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_UNDELETE => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_UNDELETE,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_OPERATOR => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OPERATOR,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_MASTER => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_MASTER,
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),

    self::PERMISSION_OWNER => array(
        MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER,
    ),
);


}

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getMasks($permission, $object)
    {
        if (!isset($this->map[$permission])) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->map[$permission];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function contains($permission)
    {
        return isset($this->map[$permission]);
    }

}
```